# How to run an object in C++ through a large range of files and functions

Tags: c++

Every time when I make projects I have a HUGE data transfer problem. As in my data is unable to get around with the way I've designed things. Is there a "correct" way to transfer data? A more neat and organized way for it to get around? I was taught very often that it is not okay to use global variables because of optimization and whatnot. But something I was never taught was alternates to globals. Is it okay to use a memory address and file that through functions instead of a global variable? For example: let's just pretend there's a huge structure in my header file:

```
#ifndef DATASTRUCTURE
#define DATASTRUCTURE

struct cat {
    int x;
    int y;
    bool alive;
};

#endif //DATASTRUCTURE
```

Now I have "a lot" of functions that derive this object.

```
#ifndef STUFF
#define STUFF

#include "dataStructure.h"

void killcat(cat* c);
void movecatx(cat* c);
void movecaty(cat* c);

#endif STUFF
```

Now in my main file, I call all those things.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dataStructure.h"
#include "stuff.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Running!\n";

    cat c;

    killcat(&c);
    movecatx(&c);
    movecaty(&c);
}
```

I watered things way down here. But in a real scenario where you have thousands and thousands of code, Is this a good way to go about things? Having all massive data structures in the main file and then just iterating functions through them?

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question perfectly, but when you transfer a pointer to a member, you only copy the pointer, not the data. So regardless the size of the structure, it will only copy the size of a pointer every time.

Comment: You should generally use references instead of pointers.

Comment: Also, you tagged your question as C++, so you can use references, or add the functions as methods in a class.

Comment: @RoyAvidan Right, the question is more about neatness and effeciency

Comment: Using pointers, references and classes are all equally efficient, as they work the same way "behind the scene". I would say that references are better here, or using classes regarding the neatness. Global variables are also efficient enough, but they raise problems and I would suggest you to avoid them.

Comment: In C++ you've got little excuse for not adding those functions like those mentioned in the question as member functions to the struct. If for some reason you don't want to add those functions to the struct itself there's still the option of creating an object containing a field with a pointer or reference you're dealing with. *"let's just pretend there's a huge structure in my header file"* This very much sounds like something went wrong in the OOA and you failed to separate the data properly into logical groups.